# Google Chrome div overflow on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script to resize all divs within a container, however it does not work correctly in Google Chrome when I reload the page. If I resize the browser width and reload the page the divs resize and text overflows the div boxes. How can I fix this? Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function resizeDivs() {

$(".container>div").height("");

$('.container').each(function(){  

    var highestBox = 0;
    $('.column', this).each(function(){

        if($(this).height() > highestBox) 
           highestBox = $(this).height(); 
    });  

    $('.column',this).height(highestBox);

});  

}



$(document).ready(function(){



$(".container>div").css('height', 'auto');

resizeDivs();


});

$(window).resize(function () {


$(".container>div").css('height', 'auto');
resizeDivs();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the resizeDivs() on window load not in document ready